# What ML algo to choose to recreate x-ray human posture

Tags: 3d-reconstruction

I have an idea and not sure how to start. I have a x-ray image Of human skull. What kind of ML algorithm whold be the best to recreate the posture of the original skull.
How I see the algo steps.

1. Have an image of skull
2. Have an 3d model of skull
3. Arrange the 3d model in space and take an virtual x-ray of it.
4. Compare the real and virtual x-rays and make the adjustments to parameters.

I do not fully understand what ML algo can give adjust the virtual's skull posture based on the error of matched x-rays.
Thanks!

Comment: I found a great video that explains one of the approaches to solve that type of tasks
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=El51TuwwqwA